# When place order its redirects to the shopping cart page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, place-order

When place order its redirects to the shopping cart page in Magento 2

I used an OrderAttributes extension to my store its not working properly, Can’t make an order when the Order attribute extension is installed.

Steps:

1. Open Admin Panel and verify that the extension is installed
2. Navigate to Order Attributes and verify that no new attributes were created
3. Go to Storefront and add a product to your cart
4. Fill out all the required fields and try to make an order

Actual Result: Can’t make an order when Order attribute extension is installed

Expected Result: Order Attribute extension should not influence the default behavior. Please, see attached file

**Error was in the place-order-mixin.js file but I can't fix an issue someone please help me to resolve this issue**

I used this module: https://github.com/sd2894/Ecomteck

Comment: Because of custom module issue, it's better to raise an issue on the custom module's github page.